# Rake not running any tests with minitest

Tags: ruby, rake, rake-task

I have a file containing a class of multiple tests (using minitest).  I have `require 'minitest/autorun'` at the top of the file and all tests run correctly when I call the file directly (`ruby my_tests.rb`).

So far, so good.  However, now I'm trying to run my tests via `rake`.

```
require "rake/testtask"
task :default => [:test]

Rake::TestTask.new do |t|
  t.libs << Dir.pwd + "/lib/examples"
  t.test_files = FileList['test/test*.rb']
end
```

Calling `rake` shows `test/my_test.rb` getting called but no tests within the class get run (0 tests, 0 assertions, etc.).  I do get these warnings:

```
...gems/minitest-5.8.0/lib/minitest/assertions.rb:17: warning: already initialized constant MiniTest::Assertions::UNDEFINED
...ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/minitest/unit.rb:80: warning: previous definition of UNDEFINED was here
```

How can I run my tests within rake successfully?  I am *not* using rails.

EDIT: Here is the top of my test file:

```
require 'minitest/spec'
require 'minitest/autorun'
require 'minitest/reporters'

reporter_options = { color: true }
Minitest::Reporters.use![Minitest::Reporters::DefaultReporter.new(reporter_options)]

class Test_PowerSpecInputs < Minitest::Test
  def setup
    @mc = TestClass.new()
  end

  def test_does_lib_have_constant
    # my test code
  end
end
```

Comment: Which version of minitest do you have installed?

Comment: minitest 5.8.0, ruby 2.1.0p0, rake 10.1.0.  I'm thinking I should update rake to the latest version and give it a shot.

Comment: Updating the version of rake did the trick.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Try changing your Rakefile to this.

```
require "bundler/gem_tasks"
require "rake/testtask"

Rake::TestTask.new(:test) do |t|
  t.libs << "test"
  t.libs << "lib"
  t.test_files = FileList['test/**/*_test.rb']
end

task :default => :test
```

Comment: I had to add a gemspec file since bundler was invoked but I'm still getting the same error.  I'll add another comment above with more details about my test file content.

Answer (score 0):

jphager2 got me thinking about tool versions and it turned out that my version of rake was fairly old.  Updating to 11.x did the trick.